KJV and NKJV Jeremiah 2:34(c) states "..I have not found it by secret search.." which is different from NASB1995, ESV, & other translations

Jeremiah 2:34-35
New King James Version
34 (a) Also on your skirts is found
(b) The blood of the lives of the poor innocents.
(c) I have not found it by [a]secret search,
(d) But plainly on all these things.
35 Yet you say, ‘Because I am innocent, Surely His anger shall turn from
me.’ Behold, I will plead My case against you, Because you say, ‘I
have not sinned.’
Jeremiah 2:34-35
King James Version
34 (a) Also in thy skirts is found (b) the blood of the souls of the
poor innocents:  (c) I have not found it by secret search,  (d) but
upon all these.
35 Yet thou sayest, Because I am innocent, surely his anger shall turn
from me. Behold, I will plead with thee, because thou sayest, I have
not sinned.


Jeremiah 2:34-35
New American Standard Bible 1995
34  (a) “Also on your skirts is found (b) The lifeblood of the
innocent poor; (c) You did not find them breaking in. (d) But in spite
of all these things,
35 Yet you said, ‘I am innocent; Surely His anger is turned away from
me.’ Behold, I will enter into judgment with you Because you say, ‘I
have not sinned.’
Jeremiah 2:34-35
English Standard Version
34 (a) Also on your skirts is found
(b) the lifeblood of the guiltless poor; (c) you did not find them breaking in.
(d) Yet in spite of all these things 35 you say, ‘I am innocent;
surely his anger has turned from me.’ Behold, I will bring you to judgment
for saying, ‘I have not sinned.’


2:34-35 The Westminster Leningrad Codex
34 גַּ֤ם בִּכְנָפַ֙יִךְ֙
נִמְצְא֔וּ דַּ֛ם נַפְשׁ֥וֹת אֶבְיוֹנִ֖ים נְקִיִּ֑ים
לֹֽא־בַמַּחְתֶּ֥רֶת מְצָאתִ֖ים כִּ֥י עַל־כָּל־אֵֽלֶּה׃
35 וַתֹּֽאמְרִי֙ כִּ֣י נִקֵּ֔יתִי אַ֛ךְ שָׁ֥ב אַפּ֖וֹ מִמֶּ֑נִּי
הִנְנִי֙ נִשְׁפָּ֣ט אוֹתָ֔ךְ עַל־אָמְרֵ֖ךְ לֹ֥א חָטָֽאתִי׃

When one reads KJV and NKJV Jeremiah 2:34(c) states "..I have not found it by secret search.." within the larger context of Jeremiah 2, it seems that God is scolding Israel by saying that it was so blatant that innocent blood was obviously spilt by Israel.
To elaborate, God did Not have to conduct a "secret search" in order to see that Israel did wrong by killing innocent people.
However, other translations like NASB1995 and ESV, and many others translate it to mean that Israel did Not even find these innocent people "breaking in" which seems to suggest that Israel did Not find the innocent people doing anything wrong.
Said translations seems to suggest that despite the "innocent people" doing Nothing wrong, Israel still kills them.
Why is KJV and NKJV's Jeremiah 2:34(c) translations so different from NASB1995 and ESV, and others?  Please refer to the Old Testament Hebrew when posting a response.

The matter in Jer 2:32 depends upon the translation of the verb מַחְתֶּרֶת (machtereth) which occurs in just two places in the OT, Ex 22:2, Jer 2:34, both the meaning of "breaking in by burglary, etc".  In both Strong's and BDB, the verb is defined thus:
STRONGS

Meaning: a burglary, unexpected examination
Word Origin: Derived from the root חָתַר (chathar), meaning "to dig" or "to bore." ...
Usage: The term "machtereth" refers to the act of breaking in or burglary, specifically the clandestine act of digging through or
breaking into a house. It is used in the context of theft or
intrusion, highlighting the secretive and unlawful nature of the act.
Cultural and Historical Background: In ancient Israel, homes were often constructed with mud bricks or stone, making it feasible for a
thief to dig through a wall to gain entry. The concept of "machtereth"
underscores the vulnerability of households to such invasions and the
need for protective measures. The Mosaic Law addressed issues of theft
and burglary, emphasizing restitution and justice, reflecting the
importance of property rights and community security in Israelite
society.

Brown-Driver-Briggs

מַחְתֶּ֫רֶת noun masculine breaking in, burglary — יִמָּצֵא הַגַּנָּב
׳אִםבַּֿמּ Exodus 22:1 i.e. caught in the act (JE); so מְצָאתִים ׳לֹא
בַּמּ Jeremiah 2:34, not in the act of breaking in didst thou find
them (2 feminine singular suffix Ges§ 44, 2, R 4), i.e. those whom
thou hast slain were not detected in crime.

I am at a loss to understand the KJV/NKJV translation of "by secret search".
